# How to add "httponly" attribute set on existing cookie ? (Magento 1)

Tags: magento-1.9, php, jquery, session, cookie

In Magento 1

```
I can see many of the cookie are without Secure flag and HttpOnly set on website.
```

**Is their any way to set Secure flag and HttpOnly set on all server Cookie ?**

I need to make all server cookie secure.

I have tried “Use HTTP Only” option in Magento to add "httponly" flag in cookies.

**System > Configuration > General > Web > Session Cookie Management**

It works but not for all cookies.
**Also i have tried**

```
override isSecure method from Mage_Core_Model_Cookie model, method:

public function isSecure() {

return $this->_getRequest()->isSecure();

}
```

But, This does not work.
Any thoughts on this ?

Thankyou

Comment: Any thoughts ??

Comment: Which cookies does it not work for? Are those cookies set by Magento or an externally loaded asset?

Comment: Hello, it does not set "Httponly" attribute to cookies created from magento function

Comment: You say "It works but not for all cookies", which cookies are those?

Comment: it does not set "Httponly" attribute to cookies created from magento function